# Why does Cycles volume rendering (absorption) seem to be tied to the objects/volume size?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

So I have the same volume absorption material applied to cubes of different sizes.
But the density seems to change based on the size of those objects, see attached image: [image]
A closeup of the material, left large cube, right small cube: [image]
Could it be that the step size for the volume integration is somehow scaled by the object dimensions, and not globally the same?

The only bad fix I have found so far is to split up my object into multiple smaller ones.

Any help is appreciated. :)

EDIT: Scale is applied for both. I added a minimal test scene as suggested in the comments: [Blendfile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qKZcaQ8Rr6fxkhSiVq0VxURDOrDZJzu1/view?usp=sharing)

EDIT 2: What I am trying to achieve is to have really dense volumetric spheres (almost opaque) over a volume of 35x35x0.1mm, with a sphere "density" of 100 spheres per 1mm. For a cube with 1x1mm the density is good, they are almost completely black / opaque.
However as the size of the object increases the spheres loose density.
See this image: [image: problem]
On the left is a single 35x35mm cube, the top shows a 35x35mm cube created with array modifiers from a single 1x1mm cube.
This shows the same decreased density as the single 35x35mm cube, compared to the 1x1mm cube the array it started from.
Only if I apply the array modifiers and separate the geometry into the individual 1x1mm cubes again I get the proper density.
However, one can see the seams between the cubes, which is bad.

I highly suspect this has to do with cycles step size used to march through the volume. I had to set it to the lowest setting, to get the spheres in the 1x1mm cube to look really black and dense.
Why does the step size seem to be somehow tied to the objects size, and how to fix this?

I also updated the scene, like shown in the last screenshot: [blendfile v2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/128LHFJrCpJOVOWJYozOFVdYfX_oQixF-/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: If you scale in Object mode, don't forget to apply the scale?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Include material set up and or scene file.

Comment: @moonboots Scale is applied for both.

Comment: @RumenBelev I updated the post with a minimal blendfile.

Comment: Hi Christian, you have selected Object output as a Texture Coordinate but you haven't pointed at any Object. Please check the Blender manual here for more information:  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html?utm_source=blender-3.6.5#bpy-types-shadernodetexcoord
 Please explain in more details what exactly are you trying to achieve and give example of the desired result.

Comment: @RumenBelev Thank you for pointing that out, I now use an empty to control the object texture coordinates. Unfortunately, the problem still remains. I am going to update my question, with a little bit more detail what I would like to do.

Comment: Hi Christian, I am afraid my computer is not designed for heavy CPU / GPU rendering.  You were on the right path - the issue is the sampling step size is calculated per volume automatically and because you have many objects it is calculated differently.  If you keep the Volume Step Rate - 0.01 in the Render Properties - there is an option for adjustment. You should try the following: Go to Material Properties >> Settings >> Volume and set the Step Rate to 0.5 or lower to equalize the volume sampling across all volumes. Edit: Set the PointsPerOBJUnit value to 90 for 10 spheres per 0.1 mm

Comment: @RumenBelev Thank you so much! Adjusting the step scale in the material settings fixed it. Didn't know that this setting existed.
PS: How can I give you credit? Will you answer it formally, so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: Hi Christian F., I am glad it helped. You can just up-vote my previous comment if you think it may be of help to someone else. Cheers!

Comment: I don't see any up-vote icon or button for these comments here. Only the flag.
Maybe if you post it as an answer I can, up vote and mark it as resolved.